# Updating JSON object using another JSON object

Tags: angularjs, json

**I am using AngularJS**

How to update the "name" and "gender" in this JSON object:

```
{ name: "John", gender: "male", status: "single", createdBy: "Andrew" }
```

With this "name" and "gender" in this JSON object:

```
{ name: "Anna", gender: "Female"}
```

The updated JSON object will be this:

```
{ name: "Anna", gender: "Female", status: "single", createdBy: "Andrew" }
```

Hoping for an informative response. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//try this...
var json1 = { 
    name: "John", 
    gender: "male", 
    status: "single", 
    createdBy: "Andrew" 
};
var json2 = { 
    name: "Anna", 
    gender: "Female"
};
//extending json2 values to json1
angular.extend(json1, json2);
```

Comment: This is just what I've been looking for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the new values to the properties,

```
   jsonObj.name = newObj.name;
   jsonObj.gender = newObj.gender;
```

**DEMO**

```js
var jsonObj = { name: "John", gender: "male", status: "single", createdBy: "Andrew" };
var newObj = { name: "Anna", gender: "Female"};
jsonObj.name = newObj.name;
jsonObj.gender = newObj.gender;
console.log(jsonObj);
```

Comment: is there no way to just like merge the two obj? Like making:

JsonObj1 = JsonObj2;

Comment: what do you mean by merge?

Comment: since you want to assign only specific properties, you cant completely assign the whole object. just assign the properties as mentioned in demo

Comment: Because this is an edit function. Some of the values of the old JSON Object are replaced by the values of the new JSON object. I just ran out of idea on how to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @Sajeetharan